# OR function with argparse with two variables on the command line in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program that accepts a file as input, does some work with the contents of the file and the pushes it out to a server.  I want to add an optional command line switch to specify a "dry run" of the program whereby it does all the file crunching, but skips doing the writes out to the server.  I am using argparse to bring in the command line arguments, but I don't see a way to do an "OR" function between the arguments.  Here is what I'm more or less looking for...

**Allowable options:**

1) prog.py inputfile servername

2) prog.py inputfile -d

3) prog.py inputfile -d servername

**Dissallowed:**

1) prog.py inputfile

I want to ensure that either the server name **"OR"** the dry run flag are on the command line.  And, if both are there... that's OK too. (hence being an OR and not an XOR).  If I use mutually exclusive with required=true, I can get the XOR; but, I can't seem to figure out how to do this as an "OR" where both can be present.  To complicate matters, the server name is a positional argument and the dry run flag is an optional argument that could be anywhere on the command line. Does anyone have an idea on how to pull this off?

Comment: You can post-process the returned `Namespace` pretty easily I would think ...

Comment: This raises the interesting question of why mutually exclusive argument groups are restricted to optional arguments. Is there a solid semantic argument against including positional arguments, or was it simpler to implement as-is? A question for the `argparse` development community, in any case.

Comment: @chepner -- I'm not sure that mutually exclusive argument groups are restricted to optional arguments.  And even if they are, that doesn't really matter for this problem since the arguements aren't mutually exclusive (including `-d` doesn't exclude `servername`).

Comment: @mgilson I tried it: `ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional`. You're right, though, that it is needlessly strict to disallow an unnecessary server name when `-d` is used when you can simply ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dry-run', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('input_file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('servername', nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.servername is None and not args.dry_run:
    parser.error("Option 'servername' is required when not in dry-run mode.")

print args
```

Examples:

```
$ ./prog.py inputfile servername
Namespace(dry_run=False, input_file=<open file 'inputfile', mode 'r' at 0x283440>, servername='servername')
$ ./prog.py inputfile -d
Namespace(dry_run=True, input_file=<open file 'inputfile', mode 'r' at 0x2cf440>, servername=None)
$ ./prog.py -d inputfile servername
Namespace(dry_run=True, input_file=<open file 'inputfile', mode 'r' at 0x1f4440>, servername='servername')
$ ./prog.py inputfile
usage: prog.py [-h] [-d] input_file [servername]
prog.py: error: Option 'servername' is required when not in dry-run mode.
```

You could also do this using a custom action and it has the same effect:

```
class ServernameAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values is None and not namespace.dry_run:
            parser.error("Option 'servername' is required when not in dry-run mode.")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

...
parser.add_argument('servername', nargs='?', action=ServernameAction)
...
```

Comment: +1. Better than my answer because it's a specific example, and actually matches the OP's case, instead of a generic one.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!  This will do nicely.

Answer (score 3):

`argparse` can't do every possible combination of validation, so it's worth learning how to add your own validation after the fact. For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(epilog='Either foo or bar (or both) must be specified.')
parser.add_argument('--foo', help='do something.')
parser.add_argument('--bar', help='do something else.')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
if not args['foo'] and not args['bar']:
  parser.error('Either foo or bar (or both) must be specified.')
```

Comment: Does a namespace have `__getitem__`?

Comment: @mgilson: Yes. The `args['foo']` syntax works with old and new versions of argparse, with both options and named positions. (Trying to write something completely general is why I edited the answer three times. And it was a waste of time; I should have just written the OP's example, as jterrace did.)

Comment: I just didn't realize that functionality was provided with `Namespace`.  It's basically a `DotDict` in the standard library.  Neat.

Comment: IIRC, the original version of argparse just used dictionaries, and when the consensus was to change it, there was an argument about TOOWTDI vs. easier migration, and there wasn't so much a conclusion as an "OK, we'll take the version that the code's already written for". So maybe it's not good to rely on…

Answer (score 0):

Since the server name is ignored if `-d` is used, give it a default value that will certainly cause an error if you try to use it (you need to validate it anyway, right?):

```
p.add_argument("server", default=None)
```

If `-d` is given, you will presumably never both to validate or use the server name, and every thing is fine. Otherwise, your code will catch the faulty server name when it attempts to validate it.

Comment: I actually did something like that while waiting for an answer.  :)  I assigned a default of 999.999.999.999 as the server IPv4 address.  Seems to work OK... but feels a bit clunky and the auto-gen argparse usage help is not clear on how to properly use the command line switches.  I know I can override the usage line; but, I would like to keep it as hands free and as automated as possible for easy updating.